# How to grab ratings array into in json

Tags: json, knockout.js

Hello StackOverflow users:

I'm tweaking a website that uses the omdb api to search for movies and I'm new to using json and Ajax. The website uses the knockout js framework. My question is: How do you setup an knockout observable command line that collects a json setting that seems like an array of info. I'm trying to grab the Ratings section of this json (The section is highlighted in **bold**)

```
{
"Title": "Batman Begins",
"Year": "2005",
"Rated": "PG-13",
"Released": "15 Jun 2005",
"Runtime": "140 min",
"Genre": "Action, Adventure, Thriller",
"Director": "Christopher Nolan",
"Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
"Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
"Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
"Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
"Country": "USA, UK",
"Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 14 wins & 71 nominations.",
"Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzc4ODgyZmYtMGFkZC00NGQyLWJiMDItMmFmNjJiZjcxYzVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
**"Ratings": [
{
"Source": "Internet Movie Database",
"Value": "8.3/10"
},
{
"Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
"Value": "84%"
},
{
"Source": "Metacritic",
"Value": "70/100"
}
],**
"Metascore": "70",
"imdbRating": "8.3",
"imdbVotes": "1,099,197",
"imdbID": "tt0372784",
"Type": "movie",
"DVD": "18 Oct 2005",
"BoxOffice": "$204,100,000",
"Production": "Warner Bros. Pictures",
"Website": "http://www.batmanbegins.com/",
"Response": "True"
}
```

These are the ko settings used to grab the data:

```
self.currentMovie = {
        Type: ko.observable(),
        Year: ko.observable(),
        Genre: ko.observable(),
        Released: ko.observable(),
        Runtime: ko.observable(),
        Poster: ko.observable(),
        Rated: ko.observable(),
        imdbRating: ko.observable(),
        imdbVotes: ko.observable(),
        Ratings:ko.observable().Source = "Rotten Tomatoes",
        Actors: ko.observable(),
        Plot: ko.observable(),
        Writer: ko.observable(),
        Director: ko.observable(),
        Country: ko.observable(),
        Language: ko.observable(),
        Title: ko.observable()

    };
```

My first impulse was to setup the observable like this:

```
Ratings:ko.observable().Source = "Rotten Tomatoes",
```

But all that did was list the info verbatim and not the rest of the info. Should I use ko.observableArray or Is there another setting I could use?

Comment: Trying to get max rating source?

Comment: Essentially. Basically, I'm trying to grab the Rotten Tomatoes Value available in the json.

Comment: Check answer and let me know if thats the same thing you are looking for

Comment: I tried the original line just after self.currentMovie, but I got some errors from the line; One stating that variable "o" was implicitly declared and expression expected at where the => is the line. I tried to "tweak the line slightly like this: self.currentMovie.Ratings = Ratings.find(o => o.Source === 'Rotten Tomatoes'); but it didn't work either. Thank you for helping me though. This stuff is weird and new to me.

Comment: So after making change did it work?

Comment: The same error occurred.According to the browser I'm debugging with (Chrome), I'm getting a "Ratings is not defined" at MyViewModel at the line where I've added the line

Comment: Where did you define ratings?

Comment: This was the error message that Chrome's developer tools window gave me.

Comment: Edited my answer. Take a look at it. If possible update your question with more details on error info and other details

Comment: Hi @Gerald if an answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, if the API is providing info as an array, you should use an Observable Array. Next, you say you want to filter the array to get only the object with the Rotten Tomatoes score, and access the 'Value' as an observable. Correct?

Knockout provides utility functions (read more [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)), including one for filtering arrays called `ko.utils.arrayFilter`. So you could do this:

```
self.currentMovie = {
....
RatingsArray: ko.observableArray(),
....
}

var ratingFilterFunction = function (obArray) {
    var trimmedArray = ko.utils.arrayFilter(obArray(), function (item) {
        return item["Source"] === 'Rotten Tomatoes';
    });
    return ko.observable(trimmedArray[0]["Value"]);
};

self.CurrentMovie.Ratings = ratingFilterFunction(self.CurrentMovie.RatingsArray);
```

Comment: 'plus 1' .. good one i totally forgot utility functions of knockout

Answer (score 0):

```js
function vm(){
var self = this;
var allList = {
"Title": "Batman Begins",
"Year": "2005",
"Rated": "PG-13",
"Released": "15 Jun 2005",
"Runtime": "140 min",
"Genre": "Action, Adventure, Thriller",
"Director": "Christopher Nolan",
"Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
"Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
"Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
"Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
"Country": "USA, UK",
"Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 14 wins & 71 nominations.",
"Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzc4ODgyZmYtMGFkZC00NGQyLWJiMDItMmFmNjJiZjcxYzVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
"Ratings": [
{
"Source": "Internet Movie Database",
"Value": "8.3/10"
},
{
"Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
"Value": "84%"
},
{
"Source": "Metacritic",
"Value": "70/100"
}
],
"Metascore": "70",
"imdbRating": "8.3",
"imdbVotes": "1,099,197",
"imdbID": "tt0372784",
"Type": "movie",
"DVD": "18 Oct 2005",
"BoxOffice": "$204,100,000",
"Production": "Warner Bros. Pictures",
"Website": "http://www.batmanbegins.com/",
"Response": "True"
}

self.Rating = ko.observable(allList.Ratings.find(o => o.Source === 'Rotten Tomatoes'));
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
 <div data-bind="text: Rating().Value">
 </div>
```

Lets say you received your JSON via ajax call into allList Object. You can get your Ratings array through `allList.Ratings` on which you can get the source you are looking for.
You can probably do

```
self.Rating = ko.observable(allList.Ratings.find(o => o.Source === 'Rotten Tomatoes'));
```

Assuming you have your required Ratings JSON in moviesRatingJson object

Comment: Still no dice. On the self.Rating = ko.observable(allList.Ratings.find(o => o.Source === 'Rotten Tomatoes')); line, it gives an error stating that the object is implicitly declared at the o => o.Source section of the command line. But your solution works. I wonder: Ray stated that omdb was providing the json info as an array. Should I add the allList var then dump the ko.obeservable lines with ko.obeservableArray lines instead?

Comment: Give it a try. At least your example Json is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using knockout.js, but I was trying to do the same thing in a C# forms apps.  The solution was to create a simple class that defines a rating...

```
internal class Rating
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

...then create an array property, of that type, in the class that is passed to the JSON deserializer

```
internal class ImdbData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Rated { get; set; }
    //...
    public Rating[] Ratings { get; set; }   // <-- ratings!
    public string Metascore { get; set; }
    public string imdbRating { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

You will then be able to access the ratings like this

```
imdbDataObject.Ratings[0].Source
"Internet Movie Database"
imdbDataObject.Ratings[0].Value
"8.4/10"
imdbDataObject.Ratings[1].Source
"Rotten Tomatoes"
imdbDataObject.Ratings[1].Value
"97%"
imdbDataObject.Ratings[2].Source
"Metacritic"
imdbDataObject.Ratings[2].Value
"84/100"
```